# VoiceOver does not repeat typed character on custom text view with UITextInput

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, uitextinput

I have custom text view that implement UITextInput. Everything works except the voiceover does not repeat the characters I typed using soft keyboard.

Is there any additional API or services I need to implement in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, now it seems that VoiceOver cannot announce the soft keyboard feedback made by native code.
But it possible to get VoiceOver feedback at text field of WebView().
So, I'm making iOS App by this way.